# ¿Como establecer una variable decremental en un ciclo anidado?

Tags: python

Me encuentro resolviendo un problema y tengo un error de lógica, el problema es el siguiente
Dado una lista con n numeros **(a)**, descomponer el numero en digitos y multiplicar cada uno de ellos por su posicion pero comenzando desde 1 no desde 0, despues realizar una sumatoria.

ejemplo

```
a = [23]

resultado = 2 * 1 + 3 * 2
resultado = 8
```

En mi código, lo primero que realice es descomponer el numero en dígitos pero están en orden inverso, es decir si el numero es 23 descompuesto queda como 3 , 2.

Por ende al realizar una multiplicación de cada **dígito** por mi variable **j** la cual incrementa con cada iteracion en 1 obtendré el resultado pero no es el desado, opte por hacer que **j** sea inverso pero no se como hacerlo, proporcionare los resultados obtenidos y los resultados deseados junto a el código que realice, agradecería si me pueden proporcionar un consejo o pista de como resolverlo

```
a = [1776]

for i in range(len(a)):
    num = a[i]
    digitos = 0
    j = 0
    suma = 0
    multiplicacion = 0

    while num > 0:
        j = j + 1
        digitos = num%10
        num = num // 10
        multiplicacion = digitos * j
        suma = suma + multiplicacion

        print('{} {} {} {}'.format(digitos, j, multiplicacion, suma))
```

```
Resultado obtenido  Resultado deseado

6 1 6 6              6 4 24 24 
7 2 14 20            7 3 21 45
7 3 21 41            7 2 14 59
1 4 4 4              1 1 1  60
```

Comment: ¿Tienes que usar el modulo para obtener los dígitos? Lo digo porque es mucho más fácil hacerlo convirtiendo a str el número.

Comment: @FJSevilla  Asi es, lo requiere el ejercicio

Comment: ok, ¿y usar una lista para almacenar los dígitos temporalmente?¿Podrias? Para hacer el contador decremental necesitas conocer el número de dígitos del entero antes de iterar.

Comment: Otra posibilidad sería usar log10 para obtener el número de dígitos del entero (requiere importar math), o iterar dos veces sobre el mismo... También se puede intentar obtener los dígitos de izq a der, pero tenemos un problema similar, o necesitamos conocer de antemano los digitos, o usar un contenedor o recursión, depende de lo que puedas usar  o no...

Comment: @FJSevilla  intente usar una lista para guardar temporalmente la variable j y quedaria [1,2,3,4], entonces bastaría con llamar el ultimo elemento en cada iteracion, pero no funciono o no se como hacerlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema de intentar hacer el contador `j` decremental es que necesitamos saber su valor máximo, es decir, necesitamos saber antes de iniciar el ciclo `while` el número de dígitos del entero.

Para resolver esto tenemos varias posibilidades, una de ellas es usar una lista para almacenar los dígitos y añadir un ciclo `for` que realice el cálculo partiendo de la lista:

```
a = [1776]

for n in a:
    suma = sum((i + 1) * int(d) for i, d in enumerate(str(n)))
    print(suma)

a = [1776]

for i in range(len(a)):
    digitos = []
    suma = 0
    num = a[i]
    while num > 0:
        digito = num % 10
        num = num // 10
        digitos.append(digito)

    num_digitos = len(digitos)
    for i in range(num_digitos):
        j = num_digitos - i
        digito = digitos[i]
        multiplicacion = digito * j
        suma += multiplicacion
        print('{} {} {} {}'.format(digito, j, multiplicacion, suma))
```

También podríamos usar el logaritmo en base 10 para obtener el número de dígitos del entero:

```
import math



a = [1776]

for num in a:
    j = int(math.log10(num)) + 1 
    suma = 0
    while num > 0:
        digito = num % 10
        num = num // 10
        multiplicacion = digito * j
        suma += multiplicacion
        j -= 1
        print(f'{digito} {j} {multiplicacion} {suma}')
```

Cuando quieras simplemente obtener los itmes de un iterable (`a` en este caso) no uses `range` + indizado, usa un ciclo `for in` sobre el iterable directamente, es más simple, eficiente y "pitónico".

Existen muchas más formas de abordar el problema, de cualquier forma, si se pueden usar todos los recursos del lenguaje, la forma más simple y eficiente de obtener la suma es:

```
a = [1776, 4032, 52]

for n in a:
    suma = sum((i + 1) * int(d) for i, d in enumerate(str(abs(n))))
    print(suma)
```

> 60
>   21
>   9